How to obtain duration time of a video embedded in a html webpage which src is a blob object without downloading it?
I would like to scrape the duration of some webpages to obtain the duration of the videos in MP4 format. The element is like
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" src="blob:https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/12f0af2d-4ae5-47f4-8288-55acc3f1b034" jw-loaded="data"></video>

ffmpeg or ffprob return 403 forbidden error.
There is also download link for the same video.
<a class="btn" id="alpha-native" href="https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/context/tampa_natives_show/article/1134/type/native/viewcontent" title="Download 373.1&nbsp;MB file." target="_blank"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>

Using mutagen.mp4 to probe this link, it takes very long time to get back duration information. I think mp4 package probably downloads whole video instead of only information part then calculate the duration.
Do you have suggestion what technique I can use to get the duration of this video without downloading the full video file?

Add the referer and user-agent headers to ffprobe:
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration -of csv="p=0" -headers "Referer: https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/" -headers "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -i "https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?params=/context/tampa_natives_show/article/1134/type/native/&path_info="

If you are using selenium/playwright, you can also just start the video then get video.duration using javascript.
